# Internal event bus with plugable consumers

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a J2EE application that receives and process messages (events).  These messages contain various blocks of data.  Different types of processing can be triggered depending of the type of data contained in a message.

I would like to have a simple internal event/message bus that can be used by the main processing thread to invoke different post-processors dependent on message content.  For example, if a message is received of type A, I would like to be able to send an internal event to all post-processors that have subscribed to events of type A.  The post-processors can then work their magic in their own time/thread.  It would be nice (though not required) if the  post-processors could be added/removed from the application via some sort of plugin-framework.

I understand that there are various message buses available.  I am really seeking advice on an appropriate (lightweight) choice or perhaps a design pattern/example to cook my own.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has and nice EventBus implementation. See the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained).

Comment: Thank you for this pointer.  I will work through the documentation and comment again later in the day.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out MBassador https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador.

It is annotation driven, very light-weight and uses weak references (thus easy to integrate in environments where objects lifecycle management is done by a framework like spring or guice or somethign). It provides an object filtering mechanism and synchronous or asynchronous dispatch/message handling. And it's very fast!

EDIT: I created a performance and feature comparison for a selection of available event bus implementations including Guava, MBassador and some more. The results are quite interesting. Check it out here
http://codeblock.engio.net/?p=37

Comment: Added more documentation. I think I will provide a performance comparison with the Guava bus in the near future.